# No strategy set in NuxtJs Auth

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I had put aside the axios calls with token for a while, I came back to them by settling it locally first, once in production I get an error that I don't understand

```
ERROR  No strategy is set!
```

Here is my NuxtJs auth configuration

```
auth: {
      strategies: {
        laravelJWT: {
          provider: 'laravel/jwt',
          url: '/api',
          endpoints: {
            login: { url: '/auth/login', method: 'post' },
            user: { url: '/auth/user', method: 'get' }
          },
          token: {
            property: 'access_token',
            maxAge: 60 * 60
          },
          refreshToken: {
            maxAge: 20160 * 60
          }
        }
      },
      plugins: ['~/plugins/api']
    }
```

My login middleware

```
import { Middleware } from '@nuxt/types'

const login: Middleware = async ({ app, env }) => {
  if (!(app.$auth.strategy as any).token.status().valid()) {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-useless-catch
    try {
      await app.$auth.loginWith('laravelJWT', {
        data: {
          email: `${env.front.email}`,
          password: `${env.front.password}`
        }
      })
      // do something on success
    } catch (e) {
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
      // console.error(e)
      throw e
    }
  }
}

export default login
```

And finally my error trace

```
ERROR  No strategy is set!

  at Auth.getStrategy (node_modules/@nuxtjs/auth-next/dist/runtime.mjs:314:0)
  at Auth.get strategy [as strategy] (node_modules/@nuxtjs/auth-next/dist/runtime.mjs:309:0)
  at login (middleware/login.ts:4:0)
  at promisify (.nuxt/utils.js:278:0)
  at middlewareSeries (.nuxt/utils.js:258:0)
  at server.js:6449:12
  at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
  at module.exports.__webpack_exports__.default (.nuxt/server.js:159:0)
2021-07-01T15:00:10.098946418Z
```

Comment: Can you try this syntax `'laravelJWT'` as shown in the documentation? https://auth.nuxtjs.org/providers/laravel-jwt This should not make a difference but who knows.

Comment: it will be the same